# Shell Script run with TaskSet

Tags: linux, loops, ubuntu, cpu

I am running the following command on ubuntu:

```
taskset -c 1 ./forLoop
```

and its giving me the following error:

```
./forLoop: 1: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

What is in forLoop is the following:

```
for ((  i = 0 ;  i <= 1000000;  i++  ))
do
  echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

simply `./forLoop` does execute by itself but I want to attach the process to a certain affinity. Can I ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely happening because you're on Ubuntu and the interpreter called `dash` gets invoked instead of `bash`.

Trivially, type this to confirm:

```
dash ./forLoop
```

You should see the same "for loop" error.

Some of the ways to fix this problem:

- Force `bash` to be used: `taskset -c 1 bash ./foo.sh`
- Write `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script.
- Alter the loop code to be dash-compatible, as described in the below link.

Read more here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh/